# Java "&" Operator

Tags: java

Could somebody explain me why `System.out.println((12 & 9));` prints `8`, please?

I do not understand the logic of the & operator at this context.

Thanks!

Comment: & is a bitwise and operator.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
It is Binary representation. (Machine Understandable language)
Here first place resembles  value - 1 (Right to Left)
Second place resembles  value - 2 (Right to Left)
Third place resembles  value - 4 (Right to Left)
Fourth place resembles  value - 8 (Right to Left)
```

**& says 1 and 1 is true(i.e., 1)**, rest of combinations are false (i.e., 0)

```
     12 - 1100
      9 - 1001
===============
      8 - 1000
```

Answer (score 18):

It's binary.

12 is `1100` and 9 is `1001`.

Applying the logical "and" `&` operator gives `1000`, which is 8.

Answer (score 4):

& is a bitwise and operator.

```
12 = 1100
9 = 1001
1100 & 1001 = 1000
1000 = 8
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic for printing 8 is the same as `System.out.println((12 + 9));` prints 21.

The operators get preference over the called method, so `and` operation is performed first then anything else is let to happen.

Here you are doing simple `logical and` which should result in 8, as following:

`12` is `1100` and `9` is `1001`.

`&` operation will result in `1000`.
where `1000` is 8.